# (VBA) Trying to make an array with 4 rows and n columns

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

```
Sub abcd()

Dim numcomps As Integer
numcomps = Range("B3").Value
Dim constants() As Integer
ReDim constants(1 To 4, 1 To numcomps)
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, compnum As Integer

For k = 1 To numcomps
compnum = Cells(k, 7).Value
   For i = 1 To 4
   constants(i, k) = Cells((compnum + 6), (i + 2)).Value

   Next i
Next k

MsgBox (constants(1, 1))
MsgBox (constants(2, 1))
MsgBox (constants(3, 1))


End Sub
```

Basically, I'm trying to make an array with 4 rows and n columns where n is given by the user as numcomps. Each column will consist of 4 constants gathered from a table in the spreadsheet. The code seems to be rewriting the values in the array each time it loops instead of creating a new column. What do I need to add/change?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of your data?

Comment: Though could not clearly understand what do you want to achieve,  1st observation is that since you are usung `For i = 1 To 4` loop you are getting values of 4 columns only i.e. i+2 i.e. 3 to 6 . 2nd point is using of `compnum = Cells(k, 7).Value` within `For k = 1 To numcomps` it changes `compnum` for each value of k. compnum is taken from column G Row equal to k in each K loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this customizing where to begin gathering data

```
Sub MultiDArray()

    ' Define variables
    Dim arrayColumns As Integer
    Dim arrayRows As Integer
    Dim constants() As Integer
    Dim initialRow As Integer
    Dim initialColumn As Integer
    Dim rowCounter As Integer
    Dim columnCounter As Integer

    ' Define how many rows
    arrayRows = 4

    ' Define how many columns
    arrayColumns = Range("B3").Value

    ' Define row to begin gathering data
    initialRow = 7

    ' Define column to begin gathering data
    initialColumn = 2

    ' Redimension array to number of rows and columns
    ReDim constants(1 To arrayRows, 1 To arrayColumns)


    ' Loop through each row
    For rowCounter = 1 To arrayRows

        ' Loop through each column
        For columnCounter = 1 To arrayColumns

            ' Gather data into array
            constants(rowCounter, columnCounter) = Cells(rowCounter + initialRow, columnCounter + initialColumn)

            ' For debugging purposes
            Debug.Print "Cell: " & Cells(rowCounter + initialRow, columnCounter + initialColumn).Address, "Row: " & rowCounter, "Column: " & columnCounter, "Value:" & constants(rowCounter, columnCounter)

        Next columnCounter

    Next rowCounter

End Sub
```